# Calculate the complexity of a nested for loop

Tags: for-loop, big-o, complexity-theory, nested-loops

I want to calculate the complexity of this nested for loop:

```
s = 0;
for(i=1; i<=n; i*=2)
   for(j=1; j<=i; j*=2)
      s++;
```

What strategy do I use to find the Big O complexity of this piece of code?

Comment: Try looking through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331479/determining-big-o-notation  I doubt anyone will just give you the answer.

Comment: @smoore: The value of *i* in the inner loop is bounded above by *n*.

Comment: Yep, just revoked my comment :-)

Comment: @smoore: happens all the time. I wasn't going to post one until I saw incorrect answers popping up.

Answer (score 3):

The outer loop marches through 1, 2, 4, 8, ... *n*, which takes O(lg *n*) steps because you can only double one O(lg *n*) times until you hit *n*.

The inner loop does the same. It only goes up to *i*, but in the final iteration of the outer loop, *i* reaches its maximum value which is again *n*, so that's also O(lg *n*).

Putting this together gives an upper bound of O((lg *n*)²), which is commonly abbreviated O(lg² *n*).

Comment: Many books consider the latter notation to mean log log n

Comment: @user1952500: I've never seen that use of lg² *n*, but that's exactly why I gave both notations (see also [math.se](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124443/whats-the-correct-notation-for-log-squared)).

Comment: loglogn means log(logn) while log^2(n) means logn*logn

Comment: While the result is correct, the analysis is crude and could easily miss the tightest bound.

Answer (score 2):

**Strategy for getting the answer yourself**

Plug in different values of n into the equation, and make a chart of how many times the innermost part of the loop runs:

```
s = 0;
for(i=1; i<=n; i*=2)
  for(j=1; j<=i; j*=2)
    s++;
```

Something like this:

```
n     num_times_inner_loop_part_runs
1     1
2     3
3     3
4     6
5     6
6     6
7     6
8     10
9     10
...
15    10
16    15
...
31    15
32    21
```

You can get these data points with a program like this:

```
int n = 9;  //change this n
int counter = 0;
for(i=1; i<=n; i*=2){
  for(j=1; j<=i; j*=2){
    s++;
    counter++;
  }
}
cout << "counter is: " <<  counter << endl;
```

Plot the `num_times_inner_loop_part` runs on an X/Y coordinate plane and you'll see a curve.

Name the curve that fits closest.  In this case, it is `X = (log(Y)^2)`

If you plot your data and `X = (log(Y)^2)`, you'll find they should overlap each other.

Therefore, the complexity of this function is `O((log(n))^2)` which is an improvement over `O(n)`

Comment: Your conclusion does not match your results. `num_times_inner_loop_part_runs = n(n + 1) / 2`. Perhaps you had `i++`  instead of `i*=2`

Comment: ooh the increment is j*=2.  I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Time analysis of this piece of code:

[image: Analysis]

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm time complexity can be portrayed formally as the following:

[image]

[This document](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/jauhar/ics202/Unit03_ComplexityAnalysis1.ppt) (last slide) might be enormously useful to you.