# What's the complexity of these two for-loops?

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

What's the time complexity of this algorithm? My initial guess is that it's **O(log[n])**?

```
int array[] = new int[100];
int counter = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++ ) {
        if ( array[i] == array[j] ) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: lmgify http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433435/calculate-the-complexity-of-a-nested-for-loop

Comment: @MrSimpleMind, that's a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. This is **O(N^2).**

Look [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html)  section 4 under "How to Determine Complexities"

Answer (score 3):

The `if` part in your code gets executed about `1 + 2 + 3 +...+ n` times (`n - i - 1` where `i = 0...n - 1`, which is equal to `0,5*n*(n+1)` which is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible answers. The technically correct one is `O(1)`, because the array has a constant length, so the number of inner loop iterations is a constant.

If we assume instead that the array is length n, then the numbers of iterations of the inner loop are n-1, n-2, n-3, ... , 1, 0. The sum of an arithmetic series of length n, starting at 0, is `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
The order is O(n^2).
```

Explanation: Suppose the array length is n.
Then for iteration of first loop:
There will n-2 iterations of second loop.
so total time will be: (n-2)+(n-2)+............(n-2)   //for n-1 times
which will be: (n-1)*(n-2).

Answer (score 0):

A formal way to deduce the time complexity of your algorithm:

[image]