# Writing two versions of a function, one for "clarity" and one for "speed"

Tags: c++

My professor assigned homework to write a function that takes in an array of integers and sorts all zeros to the end of the array while maintaining the current order of non-zero ints. The constraints are:

Cannot use the STL or other templated containers.
Must have two solutions: one that emphasizes speed and another that emphasizes clarity.

I wrote up this function attempting for speed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void sortArray(int array[], int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 1;
    int n = 0;
    for (i = j; i < size;)
    {
        if (array[i] == 0)
        {
            n++;
            i++;
        }
        else if (array[i] != 0 && j != i)
        {
            array[j++] = array[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            n++;
        }
    }
    while (j < size)
    {
        array[j++] = 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    //Example 1
    int array[]{20, 0, 0, 3, 14, 0, 5, 11, 0, 0};
    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    sortArray(array, size);
    cout << "Result :\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl << "Press any key to exit...";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs correctly, but;

- I don't know what the speed of it actually is, can anyone help me figure out how to calculate that?
- I have no idea how to go about writing a function for "clarity"; any ideas?

Comment: Your professor is an idiot. You can write code that is both clear and fast. You use comments

Comment: You should write as clear and effective code as possible all the time. Nobody ever writes second version.

Comment: Unless you are in that class of developer who always writes code that always works exaectly as the customer wants and so never needs to make any changes and/or fixes, (yes, this is an empty set), losing clarity at the expense of anything else is a really bad plan.

Comment: Code duplication is - in general - a very, vary bad idea. In real world, the two versions will be out of sync faster than you can say bad. Your code should strive to meet its deliverables - in terms of results as well as performance. If your code has such tight performance constraints that you are willing to write unclear code, you might as well drop down to assembly; nothing beats that. Otherwise, your code should be well commented and clear. The cleverness used to gain that extra edge will come back to haunt you, or whoever maintains the code.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. Your professor wants you to acknowledge that nothing is easier than writing code that nobody understands and that you have to find a good path between *truly awesome magic code* and maintainable code. By asking the question on stackoverflow you failed this exercise... Then again: Everyone who posts homework on stackoverflow is missing the point of exercise.

Answer (score 6):

I my experience, unless you have very complicated algorithm, speed and clarity come together:

```
void sortArray(int array[], int size)
{
  int item;
  int dst = 0;
  int src = 0;

  // collect all non-zero elements
  while (src < size) {
    if (item = array[src++]) {
      array[dst++] = item;
    }
  }

  // fill the rest with zeroes
  while (dst < size) { 
    array[dst++] = 0;
  }
}
```

Speed comes from a good algorithm. Clarity comes from formatting, naming variables and commenting.

Answer (score 3):

#### Speed as in complexity?

Since you are, and need, to look at all the elements in the array — and as such have a single loop going through the indexes in the range `[0, N)`—where *N* denotes the size of the input—your solution is `O(N)`.

**Further reading:**

- [Plain English explanation of big O](https://stackoverflow.com/q/487258/1090079)
- [Determining big O Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8331479/1090079)

---

#### Regarding clearity

In my honest opinion there shouldn't need to be two alternatives when implementing such functionality as you are presenting. If you rename your variables to more suitable (descriptive) names your current solution should be clear enough to count as both *performant* and *clear*.

Your current approach can be written in plain english in a *very clear* fashion:

> #### pseudo-explanation
>
> - set *write_index* to 0
> - set *number_of_zeroes* to 0
> - For each element in `array`
>
>   - If element is `0`
>   - increase *number_of_zeros* by one
>   - otherwise
>   - write element value to position denoted by *write_index*
>   - increase *write_index* by one
> - write *number_of_zeroes* `0`s at the end of `array`

Having stated the explanation above we can quickly see that `sortArray` is not a descriptive name for your function, a more suitable name would probably be `partition_zeroes` or similar.

Adding comments could improve readability, but you current focus should lie in renaming your variables to better express the intent of the code.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(I feel your question is *almost* off-topic; I am answering it from a Linux perspective; I recommend using Linux to learn C++ programming; you'll adapt my advices to your operating system if you are using something else....)</sup>

#### speed

Regarding speed, you should have two complementary approaches.

The first (somehow "theoretical") is to *analyze (i.e. think on) your algorithm* and **give** (with some proof) **its asymptotic [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)**.

The second approach (only "practical", and often pragmatical) is to **[benchmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_benchmarking_methods_and_software_tools) and [profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) your program**. Don't forget to compile with [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) enabled (e.g. using `g++ -Wall -O2` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Have a benchmark which runs for more than half of a second (so processes a large amount of data, e.g. several million numbers) and repeat it several times (e.g. using [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) command on Linux). You could also measure some time *inside* your program using e.g. [`<chrono>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) in C++11, or just [clock(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html) (if you read a large array from some file, or build a large array of pseudo-random numbers with [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) or with [random(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/random.3.html) you certainly want to measure separately the time to read or fill the array with the time to move zeros out of it). See also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html).

<sup>(You need to process a large amount of data - more than a million items, perhaps many millions of them - because computer are *very* fast; a typical "elementary" operation -a [machine instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code)- takes less than a nanosecond, and you have lot of uncertainty on a single run, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8587043/841108))</sup>

#### clarity

Regarding clarity, it is a bit subjective, but you might try to make your code readable and concise. Adding a *few* good comments could also help.
Be careful about naming: [sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) is not exactly what your program is doing (it is more *moving* zeros than sorting the array)...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best - Of course you may wish to use doxygen or some other

```
// Shift the non-zeros to the front and put zero in the rest of the array
void moveNonZerosTofront(int *list, unsigned int length)
{
   unsigned int from = 0, to = 0;

   // This will move the non-zeros
   for (; from < length; ++from) {
      if (list[from] != 0) {
          list[to] = list[from];
          to++;
      }
   }

   // So the rest of the array needs to be assigned zero (as we found those on the way)
   for (; to < length; +=to) {
     list[to] = 0;
   }
}
```